# Linear algebra question- Find value a so that the matrix can be diagonalized

Tags: linear-algebra

I was given the following matrix \begin{bmatrix} 5&4&4\\a&1&0\\-a&0&1 \end{bmatrix} and i was asked to calculate a so that the matrix can be diagonalized using the similarity transformation

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Show what you’ve done first.

Comment: [ 5   4      4           ]
[ 0   1  -4a+4          ]
[ 0   0  a^2-a+4(4a-4)/(5a+4)] i reduced the matrix using gaussian elimination thats all i have done

Comment: That calculation gets the eigenvalues for you. If the eigenvalues are all different, then it's guaranteed that the matrix can be diagonalized. If there is a repeated eigenvalue, you have to work a little harder to see whether there are enough linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: For $a=0$ it is diagonaliazable.

Comment: @BobDobbs that's what i thought at first but it said to use similarity transformation that why i used gauss to reduce the matrix

Comment: Find a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 3):

A matrix is diagonalizable if and only if the minimal polynomial is square free.   Another description is that the degree of $(x- \lambda)$  in the minimal polynomial is the size of the largest Jordan block for $\lambda$

Call your matrix $M.$  The characteristic polynomial is
$$ x^3 - 7 x^2 + 11x  -5 = (x-1)^2 (x-5)$$

This might also be the minimal polynomial, we need to check. The other possibility is $ (x-1) (x-5) = x^2 - 6x + 5$

However, we calculate that
$$
M^2 - 6 M + 5 I =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0&0&0 \\
0&4a&4a \\
0&-4a&-4a
\end{array}
\right)
$$
When $a=0,$  this is the zero matrix and $M$ can be digonalized. When $a \neq 0$ this result is not the zero matrix, and $M$ cannot be diagonalized.

Cute problem

Answer (score -1):

For a matrix to be diagonalizable, the algebraic multiplicities of its eigenvalues must equal the geometric multiplicities. First, we find $\det(\lambda I-A)$, hence:
$$
\begin{align}
\det(\lambda I-A) &= 0, \\
\det \Big( \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0 & 0\\0&\lambda&0\\0&0&\lambda \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 4 & 4\\a&1&0\\-a&0&1 \end{bmatrix} \Big) &=0 \implies (\lambda-5)(\lambda-1)^2 = 0.
\end{align}
$$
For $\lambda_1 = 1$, its algebraic multiplicities is 2. This eigenvalue must have two eigenvectors (i.e. geometric multiplicities) for the matrix to be diagonalizable; therefore, we need to compute $(\lambda I - A) x = 0$. For $\lambda_1$, we get
$$
\begin{align} 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1\\a&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}
$$
If $a=0$, we have two eigenvectors(i.e. $[-1,1,0]^T,[-1,0,1]^T$) and the matrix is diagonalizable since the algebraic multiplicities match the geometric multiplicities). If $a\neq 0$, you end up with one eigenvector for $\lambda_1$; therefore, the matrix is not diagonalizable.